# AngularJS ng-click chamado duas vezes

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, angularjs-directives

Eu estou utilizando o `ng-click` para fazer uma chamada comum de javascript. Porém ele está sendo chamado/disparado duas vezes quando clico na chamada.

Minha diretiva:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('cadastrarPost', cadastrarPost);

cadastrarPost.$inject = ['$ionicPopup', '$ionicPopover'];

function cadastrarPost($ionicPopup, $ionicPopover) {

    var ddo = {
        templateUrl: 'pages/ingressos/cadastrarPost.html',
        replace: true,
        restrict: "E",
        link: link,
    }


    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        function salvar() {
            ...
        }
    }

    return ddo;
}
```

Meu html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- Aplicação -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Diretivas -->
    <script src="pages/inicio/cadastrarPost.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <ion-nav-view>
        <ion-view cache-view="false" can-swipe-back="false">
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-light">
                <span ng-if="!vm.ingresso.id">
                    <button class="button button-clear text-uppercase" ng-click="salvar()">Salvar</button>
                </span>
            </ion-header-bar>
        </ion-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: esse não é um comportamento padrão, seu código deve ter alguma inconsistência, mas faz o seguinte, passa $event no ng-click e na função salvar adicione event.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após muita pesquisa, inclusive esta nesta longa discussão de possibilidades ([Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709297/angularjs-ng-click-fires-twice/45552633#45552633)) consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma:

> Trocar o ng-click pelo on-tap do IONIC

Pelas minhas pesquisas, parece que existe um bug nesse `ion-header-bar`. Tanto que fora dele funcionava perfeitamente, além disso, este bug só apareceu em versões de Android < 5.x.

Segue como ficou o código. Apenas a correção na linha do button.

```
<ion-nav-view>
        <ion-view cache-view="false" can-swipe-back="false">
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-light">
                <span ng-if="!vm.ingresso.id">
                    <button class="button button-clear text-uppercase" on-tap="salvar()">Salvar</button>
                </span>
            </ion-header-bar>
        </ion-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
```